# SQL Database Wildcard

Tags: sql, database, wildcard

I'm writing some SQL to gather results. The results however are stored on multiple databases (per year.) eg . [Results2015] , [Results2016], [Results2017].

At the minute i can union these all together as all table names are the same within each database.

My problem is when we come to 2018 there will be a new database [Results2018]. Is there a way i can gather information from databases by using [Results20] similar to a wildcard or so, therefore not having to change the SQL by adding another union each year.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic sql?

Comment: Microsoft T-SQL

Comment: How often will you run this report? And I'm guessing you'll only be adding this UNION once per new year, so you may be creating more work than it's worth. ie The UNION query should take you 30 or so seconds to copy/paste into the existing query. In 20 years, you've spent 10 minutes on it. I'd argue that spending more than 10 minutes to write, verify and debug a dynamic SQL statement will negate any time you've saved. Especially when it comes to the next developer trying to decipher what you're query is doing.

Comment: If you don't already use a reporting database, it might would be better to pull away from your production data, then just use a view to link and report on these tables. Or copy the data back into a reporting table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a select query as aggregation of every tables or databases you have and after it you can use with or insert in a local temporary table. after this point it became your unique data source.

Ex:

```
Declare @mydata table (name varchar(50), country varchar(10), population int)

insert @mydata
Select col1 as name, col2 as country,col5 as population from new_york.dbo.table_a
union all
Select col3, col12, col55 from Pittsburgh.dbo.table_t
union all
Select col1, col2,col5 from Rio.dbo.table_ab

-- after it just use @mydata as data source
```

I hope it help you, all the best

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @MytabName varchar(128)
declare @v_sql    varchar(max)
declare @cnt      integer = 1

while @cnt < datepart("y", getdate())-2000 
loop
set @MytabName = 'Results20' + @cnt
set @v_sql = 
'insert into ' + @MytabName + '
select t1.stuff
from [db].[schema].[table] t1
where t1.SomeColumn = ''SomeValue'' '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @v_sql

set @cnt = @cnt+1
end
```